# This Promise.raceWithIndex() function returns an index, promise pair - however a slight code change results in silent program crash - why?

Tags: javascript, promise

This `PromiseRaceWithIndex()` function returns an [index, promise] pair.  (C.f. Promise.race() which returns only the promise without the index).  **This code works perfectly**.

```
async function PromiseRaceWithIndex(ap){
  async function snooze(ms){ 
    return new Promise(r=>{setTimeout(r,ms);});
  }
  await Promise.race(ap);
  for (let i=0; i<ap.length; i++){
    if (!(ap[i] instanceof Promise))
      return [i,ap[i]];
    else {
      // without using square brackets around the return values 
      // (and correspondingly around test) the program silently crashes
      let [test]=await Promise.race([
        (async ()=>{ return [await ap[i]];})(),
        (async ()=>{ await snooze(0); return [ap[i]];})(),
      ]);
      if (!(test instanceof Promise))
        return [i,test];
    }
  }
}
```

*([This **perfectly working code**](https://jsfiddle.net/craigphicks/hjr78q2a/) is demonstrated in *JSFiddle*.  On that page press "run" and then click 'console' in bottom right quad to see the output.)*

However, the code can be changed from perfectly working code to buggy code if the following lines are substituted in -

```
      let test=await Promise.race([
        (async ()=>{ return await ap[i];})(),
        (async ()=>{ await snooze(0); return ap[i];})(),
      ]);
```

i.e., if the square brackets are removed from around `[test]`, `[await ap[i]]`, and `ap[i]`. **Then program will silently exit** the first time it enters the call to `Promise.race([...])`.  This phenomena is confirmed both in *JSFiddle* and running under *Node 12LTS* in Linux.

Certainly it is "buggy" to exit suddenly without an error message. However, as a separate issue, **is there a logical reason to terminate processing at that point?**.

The only difference I can see is that by returning their results in single element arrays, the promises will not be "re-wrapped" as they are passed out through the arrow functions. But I can't see any reason why that should be a problem.

Comment: Is it because `new Promise(()=>{})` creates a promise that never resolves? With the brackets, the second race entry returns an array, ending the race. Without the brackets, the second entry returns a promise which continues the race. Since that returned promise never resolves, the race continues indefinitely. (I'm not entirely sure that's how it works, though.)

Comment: @Ouroborus -  I think that makes good sense as far implying it should hang there.   What about the jump from hanging to exiting.  I think it is because there are no more events in the event queue (in this small test program), and that is a condition which forces the program terminate without further processing.  So actually it is a good demonstration of how a js program can legally end in the middle of a  function.

Comment: You say "legally end" but really this never actually ends. It just sits there, waiting. It wouldn't get garbage collected either. The impact is probably minuscule unless you're creating a lot of that kind of promise.

Comment: I'd like to, but I don't known if my guess is actually right. I'm not entirely sure if a promise returning a promise works like that. It's just speculation on my part.

Comment: @Ouroborus - Running it under node in a terminal it actually ends the program.  The program exits without error and the shell command  prompt appears.  That is the nature of 'node' programs.  In a browser it is different.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The promise's callback obviously did exit as it has an empty body. So, at worst, it just eats up a little memory.

Comment: @Ouroborus - Here's a page on node's github issues discussing programs exiting without error on an empty event stack - https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22088#issuecomment-465380046 .  Are you convinced now that your answer is correct?

Comment: Yeah, they seem to have a similar issue. I was looking elsewhere and it seems that, if nothing is going on and nothing is in the queues, node assumes everything is done and exits even if there are `await`s waiting. Personally, I would much rather my code hung rather than mysteriously exit when I believe it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

```js
/**
 * @type {<T>(promises: Promise<T>[]) => Promise<{ value: T, i: number }>}
 */
function racePromisesIndex(promises) {
    return Promise.race(promises.map((promise, i) => promise.then(value => ({ value, i }))))
}
```

here's much simpler race promises with index function in case anyone wants it

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @Ouroborus in the comments to the original post

> Without the brackets, the second entry returns a promise which continues the race.

As for why it doesn't hang, but exits instead, it is because the event queue has emptied (when run in *node* from a terminal).  This can be confirmed by adding the following line to end of the program

```
process.on('beforeExit',(code)=>{console.log(`beforeExit ${code}`);});
```

*(Note: doesn't work on the JSFiddle page because the `process` variable is not exposed.)*

The `beforeExit` event is documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_beforeexit).